# Difference between searching and substituting pattern matching

Tags: neovim, search, substitute

I have a string in a JSON file which is repeated with different values for chance. I want to replace all of these blocks by moving the miss chance out of the attack array and into a separate property.

```js
"attacks": [
  {
    "name": "miss",
    "chance": "0.25"
  },
  ...
]
```

```js
"missChance": 0.25,
"attacks": [
  ...
]
```

I managed to write a (basic) search pattern that would find all of these bits of JSON, and had grouping so I would be able to pull out the chance:

```
/"attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},
```

However, although this search pattern would find all of the occurrences I wanted to replace, when I use it in a substitute command it returns "Pattern not found". The substitute I was using was:

```
:%s/"attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},/"missChance": \1^M"attacks": [/g
```

I have noticed that the error includes more of the search pattern than I expected; it looks like it's searching for everything after the second "/" separator for some reason. Why would the search be different in the substitute command to in a normal search?

This is the error:
`Pattern not found: "attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},/"missChance": \1,^M"attacks": [/g`

Comment: For the future, you may want to consider using a macro instead of a convoluted substitute. You can sequence the macro such that it starts with a normal search to get to where you need to be, so repeated uses of the macro is effectively identical to `:s///g`, but likely far less complicated to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to escape the opening square bracket, otherwise the whole command becomes the pattern.

```
:%s/"attacks":\s*\[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},/"missChance": \1^M"attacks": [/g
                 ^
```

---

If you don't escape it, the pattern in this substitution command:

```
:%s/"attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},/"missChance": \1^M"attacks": [/g
```

is not:

```
"attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},
```

but instead:

```
"attacks":\s*[\_s*{\_s*"name":\s*"miss",\_s*"chance":\s"\(0\.\d*\)"\_s*},/"missChance": \1^M"attacks": [/g
```

This is explained at `:h E769`:

> When the ']' is not there Vim will not give an error message but
>   assume no collection is used.  Useful to search for '['.  However, you
>   do get E769 for internal searching.  And be aware that in a
>   `:substitute` command the whole command becomes the pattern.  E.g.
>   ":s/[/x/" searches for "[/x" and replaces it with nothing.  It does
>   not search for "[" and replaces it with "x"!